Estrutura IF/else if/else no CMD
Tem um pequeno trecho de um script CMD, onde eu quero simplificar uma estrutura if para que alguns else if fiquem em uma só linha, pois os comandos dentro dele são os mesmos.
Segue o trecho.
:executeInstaller
if "%programID%"=="Mozilla.Firefox" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /StartMenuShortcuts /DesktopShortcut=false /TaskbarShortcut=true /PrivateBrowsingShortcut=true /MaintenanceService=false /RegisterDefaultAgent=false"
) else if "%programID%"=="Notepad++.Notepad++" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!""
) else if "%programID%"=="Microsoft.PowerShell" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!""
) else if "%programID%"=="Microsoft.NuGet" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" nuget.exe update -self"
) else if "%programID%"=="Google.GoogleDrive" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!""
) else if "%programID%"=="Microsoft.DirectX" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!""
) else if "%programID%"=="Piriform.Defraggler" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!""
) else if "%installer_type%"=="msi" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /i /quiet /norestart"
) else if "%installer_type%"=="msix" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /install /quiet /norestart"
) else if "%installer_type%"=="exe" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /S"
) else if "%installer_type%"=="inno" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /CURRENTUSER"
) else if "%installer_type%"=="nullsoft" (
    set "install_command="!file_path!" /S"
) else if "%installer_type%"=="msstore" (
    if "%architecture%"=="--architecture x64" (
        set "install_command=winget install -e --id %programID% --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --silent --disable-interactivity %architecture%"
    ) else (
        set "install_command=winget install -e --id %programID% --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --silent --disable-interactivity"
    )
) else (
    echo ERRO: Tipo de instalador desconhecido ou não tratado.
    exit /b 1
)


Se entendi, provavelmente o que você deseja é o equivalente de OR de outras linguagens, mas não existe um equivalente, existem soluções que o pessoal sugere que chega perto do resultado, como usar goto, for. Com for seria algo como for %%A in ("Notepad++.Notepad++" "Microsoft.DirectX" "foo" "bar" "val5") do if "%VAR%"==%%A set "install_command="!file_path!"", mas note que ficaria algo gigante, difícil de entender e de dar manutenção.

Aparentemente o melhor seria setar set "install_command="!file_path!"" antes das IFs, para servir um comando padrão, e então criar IFs para os comandos que exigem valores diferentes.
